# How can I add adsense for ajax in a Vaadin app?

Tags: gwt, adsense, vaadin

I am trying to add google adsense for ajax into a Vaadin webapp, but I can not figure out how to do this without creating a custom GWT component. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check http://dev.vaadin.com/browser/incubator/NativeJS/

With this widget you can add the adsense javascript code.